# Play Audio from other apps

Tags: ios, audio, mpmusicplayercontroller

So when I launch my app, I want to be able to tell when music from another app is playing (system, soundcloud, pandora, spotify, etc).

I am able to do so with this:

```
BOOL isOtherAudioPlaying = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] isOtherAudioPlaying];
if (isOtherAudioPlaying){
    NSLog(@"Playing Music");
}else{
    NSLog(@"Not Playing Music");
}
```

And I am able to play/pause the iPod music player with the following code:

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] play];
[[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] pause];
```

However, this only works if I am using the default iOS Music app.

If I listen to music from another app (SoundCloud for example). The code does not work. It will still play/pause the iOS Music app.

**Question:**

Is there any way of playing/pausing music that is being currently played regardless of the app?

Comment: You cannot control other apps.

Comment: I'm not incorrect. These are the things you can do with regard to audio from other apps: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/ConfiguringanAudioSession/ConfiguringanAudioSession.html These and no other.

Comment: matt you are correct. Went through the documentation and got the desired effect I was going for. thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I needed to play and record audio at the same time and had trouble with the stopping of background music.

I was able to do so with this audio setup:

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setActive: NO error: nil];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord  withOptions: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:nil];
[audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];
```

**Here is a table of audio session categories which will help you find the category for your desired effect.**
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/ConfiguringanAudioSession/ConfiguringanAudioSession.html

**Here is the entire Audio Session Program Guide which helped me learn more and solve my problem**
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionCategoriesandModes/AudioSessionCategoriesandModes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH10-SW1

Comment: But that is effectively just the same answer that I gave you (and that Daniel Storm gave you - his answer is now deleted).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way of playing/pausing music that is being currently played regardless of the app?

Set your AVAudioSession's category to Playback (or similar) and activate it. Any background audio being played by other apps will stop.

Comment: I do not want the background music to stop. I want to be able to control it, play/pause it.

Comment: You can't do that. Those are not your app, are they?

Answer (score 0):

matt is correct, you have no control over whether other audio is paused or not. You have to:

1. Start your audio session
2. Be prepared to handle whatever the system does

[How The System Resolves Competing Audio Demands](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/ConfiguringanAudioSession/ConfiguringanAudioSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH2-SW7)